# Understanding a line of C code containing braces and brackets

Tags: c

The code is question is:

`unsigned int iomask[]={1UL<<4};`

I understand the left shift binary operation, but I do not understand the function of the `{}` and `[]`. Could anyone help?

Comment: This is a standard array declaration and initialization. Stack Overflow does not exist to teach programming fundamentals.

Answer (score 2):

The `[]` tells you that `iomask` is an array whose size is determined by its initializer.  The `{}` is that initializer.  It can be used to initialized arrays or structs.

In this case, the initializer contains a single element, so `iomask` is an array of 1 element.

Comment: Thanks dbush - to followup, would you happen to have an idea as to why we would need an array - if it has only one element, why don't we just use `iomask` as a scalar?

Comment: @DDC Generally, you wouldn't need an array in this case.  There's probably some context missing that might explain it.

Comment: Note that you can optionally have braces in `int x = { 0 };` though it is more conventional (traditional) to leave them out.  There was a question where this arose as an issue in the last week.  The relevant section of the C11 standard is in §6.7.9 Initialization ¶11: _The initializer for a scalar shall be a single expression, optionally enclosed in braces._  The same verbiage was in C99 and even C89/C90 (different section numbers, though).

Answer (score 2):

`[ ]` simply indicates how many elements (or, dimension) are in the array, however, C compilers allow the array dimension to be omitted, and will infer the number based on the number of elements listed.

```
int iomask[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

is equal to

```
int iomask[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

where the `{ }` contain the initializers for the elements of the array.

In your example, `iomask` has 1 element, the `1UL<<4`